# Python os.chdir() not working with path with spaces and special characters

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to run some files sequentially (`scrape.py`, `tag.py`, `save.py` and `select.py`) that are located in a folder named 'cargen'. However, when I try to make os.chdir(path) to access this 'cargen' folder, I'm getting an Exception message because in the path to 'cargen' folder there's a directory with spaces and special characters on it.

The code to run the files sequentially looks like the following:

```
import os
path = "C:/Users/Desktop/repl/Special Cháracters/cargen/"

os.chdir(path)

directory = 'C:/Users/Desktop/scrap/'

files = ['scrape', 'tag', 'save', 'select']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    [os.system('python ' + path + f'{file}.py ' + directory) for file in files]
```

The message that I'm getting looks like this:

```
python: can't open file 'C:/Users/Desktop/repl/\Special': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried to move to files to a path where there aren't any special characters or spaces in the path and the code works perfectly. Could anybody please help me with this? How should I define the path to 'cargen' to be able to access these files?

**NOTE: I'm using Windows 10 with Anaconda**

Comment: Stop using `os.system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem wasn't the `os.chdir()`. The problem was related to `os.system()` function as @user2357112 mentioned.

The `os.system()` command was giving me problems due to the spaces in the `path`. Thus, as the files are all located in the same folder, I have just eliminated that reference to `path`, resulting in something like:

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()

os.chdir(path)

directory = 'C:/Users/Desktop/scrap/'

files = ['scrape', 'tag', 'save', 'select']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    [os.system('python ' + f'{file}.py ' + directory) for file in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

When windows reads comands it uses spaces as separators. e.g.:

`my folder` -> `command1: my, command2: folder`

But you can join them adding quotation marks you can join the separated commands in one.

`"my folder"` -> `command1: my folder`

I think something similiar is appening to you, try to declare your path like that:

`'"your path"'`

Comment: Hi @Sagitario thanks for your quick answer! I've tried the solution that you propose, but it doesn't work. It returns an error that says: `[WinError 123] The file name, the directory name or the syntaxis of the volume label are not correct: '"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\repl\\Special Cháracters\\cargen\\"'`

Comment: Try to use os.path.join () to join the diferents parts of the path and os.startfile () to launch the files.